# Formulating a tailor-made Maximum Flow problem in a directed graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, mathematical-optimization

Let a digraph, `G`, be given, where `t[i,j]` and `a[j,i]`, respectively, denote transfer capacity of `i` allocated for transferring its information to `j` and absorption capacity of `j` allocated for absorbing information coming from `i`. The term, `x[i]`, defines the information holding capacity of vertex `i`. If the amount of information inflowing to vertex `i` is larger than its capacity, then vertex `i` will refuse the extra information.

The following `code` generates an example digraph `G` with `n=6`:

```
Clear[trs, abs, info, edgeCapMat, system1, reducedSystem1, sa, wG1];
SeedRandom[14];
n = 6;
d = 0.3;
G1 = RandomGraph[{Round[n], Round[n*(n - 1)*d]}, 
   DirectedEdges -> True];

trs = Table[ Table[t[i, j], {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}];
abs = Table[ Table[a[i, j], {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}] // Transpose;
info = Table[x[i], {i, 1, n}];
infoStocks[stock_] := DiagonalMatrix[stock];
edgeCapMat[trsCap_, absCap_] := (trsCap*absCap) - 
   DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[trsCap*absCap]]; (* @JMissomewhatokay's contribution *)
system1 = infoStocks[info].edgeCapMat[trs, abs];

reducedSystem1 = 
 AdjacencyMatrix[G1]*
  system1;  (* the system associated with AdjacencyGraph "G" *)
sa = SparseArray[reducedSystem1];
wG1 = Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"],
   DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name" , 
  EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]; (* symbolic weighted-G1 *)

(* @kglr's contribution  *)
ClearAll[edgeW];
edgeW = Module[{g = #, 
     e = DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ 
       FindPath[##, \[Infinity], All]}, 
    Transpose[{e, PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ # & /@ e}]] &;

edgeW[wG1, 5, 2]
HighlightGraph[wG1, edgeW[wG1, 5, 2][[All, 1]]]
```

[image]

(Note: `Mathematica Code` to produce `G` has been developed by `@kglr` (many of us know `@kglr` from his contributions in MSE):

One can formulate a `Maximum Flow` problem for each path in `G`. Below I present an example `max-flow` problem from vertex `5` to vertex `2`. (This is only one of the 30 potential problems with `n=6`.)

To understand what I am doing, one may simply follow the digraph `G` given above. Some of the vertices and parameters are not required for the paths from 5 to 2. For example, `t[2]==0` and `a[5]==0` are irrelevant by construction, and vertex 6, not involved in any of the paths concerned, should be excluded from the following specific problem formulation.

```
Clear[objFn, constraintsAll, choiceVars, fc1, fc2, fc3, fc4, fc5, fc6, fct1, fct2, fct3, fct4, fct5, fca1, fca2, fca3, fca4, fca5, bc1, bc2, bc3, bc4, tc1, tc2, tc3, tc4, ac1, ac2, ac3, ac4];

(* Given *)
{x[1] = 5,   x[2] = 9,   x[3] = 3,   x[4] = 6,   x[5] = 7,   x[6] = 2};
{t[1] = 0.7, t[2] = 0,   t[3] = 0.8, t[4] = 0.3, t[5] = 0.8, t[6] = 0.4};
{a[1] = 0.9, a[2] = 0.7, a[3] = 0.6, a[4] = 0.7, a[5] = 0,   a[6] = 0.7};

Maximize ObjFn = t[5,3] a[3,5] x[5]
subject to:

(* feasibility constraints for: vertex information stock capacity *)
fc1 = t[5, 3] a[3, 5] x[5] <= x[3];
fc2 = t[3, 4] a[4, 3] x[3] <= x[4];
fc3 = t[3, 1] a[1, 3] x[3] <= x[1];
fc4 = t[4, 2] a[2, 4] x[4] <= x[2];  (* NEW: to be added *)
fc5 = t[1, 2] a[2, 1] x[1] <= x[2];  (* NEW: to be added *)
fc6 = t[4, 2] a[2, 4] x[4] + t[1, 2] a[2, 1] x[1] <= x[2]; (* NEW: to be added *)

(* feasibility constraints for: attention allocation *)
fct1 = 0 <= t[5, 3] <= 1;
fct2 = 0 <= t[3, 4] <= 1;
fct3 = 0 <= t[3, 1] <= 1;
fct4 = 0 <= t[4, 2] <= 1;
fct5 = 0 <= t[1, 2] <= 1;

fca1 = 0 <= a[3, 5] <= 1;
fca2 = 0 <= a[4, 3] <= 1;
fca3 = 0 <= a[1, 3] <= 1;
fca4 = 0 <= a[2, 4] <= 1;
fca5 = 0 <= a[2, 1] <= 1;

(* flow balancing conditions: inflow into i = outflow from i *)
bc1 = t[5, 3] a[3, 5] x[5] == (t[3, 4] a[4, 3] + t[3, 1] a[1, 3]) x[3]; (* inflow from 5 to 3 = outflow from 3 to 4 and 1 *)
bc2 = t[3, 4] a[4, 3] x[3] == t[4, 2] a[2, 4] x[4]; (* inflow from 3 to 4 = outflow from 4 to 2 *)
bc3 = t[3, 1] a[1, 3] x[3] == t[1, 2] a[2, 1] x[1]; (* NEW to be added: inflow from 3 to 1 = outflow from 1 to 2 *)
bc4 = t[4, 2] a[2, 4] x[4] + t[1, 2] a[2, 1] x[1] == t[5, 3] a[3, 5] x[5]; (* NEW to be added: total inflow to 2 = total outflow from 5 *)

(* transfer attention allocation constraints *)
tc1 = t[5, 3] <= t[5]; (* v5 allocates its total transfer attention to v3 *)
tc2 = t[3, 4] + t[3, 1] <= t[3]; (* v3 allocates its total transfer attention to v4 and v1 *)
tc3 = t[4, 2] <= t[4];
tc4 = t[1, 2] <= t[1];

(* absorption attention allocation constraints *)
ac1 = a[3, 5] <= a[3]; (* choice variable of v3 because v3 decides how much attention it should allocate for receiving information from v5 *)
ac2 = a[4, 3] <= a[4]; (* the same argument as above *)
ac3 = a[1, 3] <= a[1];
ac4 = a[2, 4] + a[2, 1] <= a[2]; (* v2 allocates its total attention b/w v4 and v1 *)

(* list of constraints *)
constraintsAll = {fc1, fc2, fc3, fc4, fc5, fc6, fct1, fct2, fct3, fct4, fct5, fca1, fca2, fca3, fca4, fca5, bc1, bc2, bc3, bc4, tc1, tc2, tc3, tc4, ac1, ac2, ac3, ac4};

(* list of choice variables: find the optimal values of these vars *)
choiceVars = {t[5, 3], t[3, 4], t[3, 1], t[4, 2], t[1, 2], a[3, 5], 
a[4, 3], a[1, 3], a[2, 4], a[2, 1]}

Maximize[{objFn, constraintsAll}, choiceVars]
```

The solution:

```
{2.16, {t[5, 3] -> 0.786664, t[3, 4] -> 0., t[3, 1] -> 0.8, t[4, 2]->0.278239, 
t[1, 2] -> 0.671632, a[3, 5] -> 0.392253, a[4, 3] -> 4.26136*10^-10, 
a[1, 3] -> 0.9, a[2, 4] -> 0., a[2, 1] -> 0.643209}}
```

**Note**: The above `max-flow` is only for the paths from 5 to 2. I want to solve the same problem for each one of the existing paths in `G`, and each problem should give me a set of values for `{t[i,j], a[j,i]}` that maximize the relevant objective function. Needless to say, each problem will have its own specific constraints and objective function to maximize.

**Question**

How can I automate the above problem formulation to find the `system-wide optimal values for each path`, i.e., `{t[i,j], a[j,i] for all i and j}`?.

(Note: This question is a simplified version of a question asked in MSE before. I made some improvement in the formulation.)

Comment: one more question:  are `a[6]` , `t[6] ` and `x[6]` really needed as part of the formulation? Or can we just restrict attention to  the subgraphs associated with the paths between node 5 and node 2?

Comment: Given `x[3] == 2`, and `x[4] == 1`,  the proposed solution violates constraint `bc2`. Check `soln = {t[5, 3] -> 0.8, t[3, 4] -> 0.31903, t[3, 1] -> 0.48097, 
   t[4, 2] -> 0.3, t[1, 2] -> 0.7, a[3, 5] -> 0.6, a[4, 3] -> 0.7, 
   a[1, 3] -> 0.9, a[2, 4] -> 0., a[2, 1] -> 0.7};
bc2 = t[3, 4] a[4, 3] x[3] == t[4, 2] a[2, 4] x[4];
bc2 /. {x[3] -> 2, x[4] -> 1} /. soln`

Comment: Tebernus, `bc123` rewrites `bc1` assuming `bc2` and `bc3` are satisfied; but this does not mean you can eliminate `bc2` and `bc3`. You still need the flow balance at nodes 4 and 2. If you add `bc2` and `bc3` to the constraint set, the proposed solution still violates `bc2`. Imho, easier way to get around infeasibilities is to change the attention allocation constraints to inequalities (allowing some part of attention budgets to be unspent).

Comment: you are most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First added `x[i]`s as `VertexCapacity`s to `wG1` so that we can later extract all the model elements from `wG1`:

```
wG1 = Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"],
   DirectedEdges -> True, VertexCapacity -> {i_ :> x[i]}, 
   VertexSize -> .2,  EdgeLabels ->  "EdgeWeight"];
SetProperty[wG1, VertexLabels -> 
    {i_ :>  Placed[PropertyValue[{wG1, i}, VertexCapacity], Center]}]; 

HighlightGraph[wG1, edgeW[wG1, 5, 2][[All, 1]]]
```

[image]

All functions below take three arguments, a graph, a source vertex and a sink vertex:

```
ClearAll[decisionVarsF, subGraphF, feasibleF, vInfoStockCapF, attentionAllocationF, 
 flowBalanceF, allConstraintsF , modelF, instanceF]

subGraphF =   Module[{el = edgeW[##][[All, 1]]}, 
    Graph[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@el] , 
         VertexCapacity -> {v_ :> PropertyValue[{#, v}, VertexCapacity]}, 
         EdgeWeight -> {e_ :> PropertyValue[{#, e}, EdgeWeight]}]] &;
decisionVarsF  = Union@Flatten[EdgeList[subGraphF[##]] /. 
      DirectedEdge[v1_, v2_] :> {t[v1, v2], a[v2, v1]}] & ;
feasibleF = Thread[0 <= decisionVarsF [##] <= 1] &; 
flowBalanceF = Module[{g = subGraphF[##]}, 
    Equal @@ (Total[PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ 
       Cases[EdgeList[g], #] ] & /@ {DirectedEdge[#, _] , 
          Reverse[DirectedEdge[#, _] ]}) & /@  Most[Rest[VertexList@g]] ] & ;
 attentionAllocationF = Module[{gb = GatherBy[EdgeList[ subGraphF[##]] /. 
    DirectedEdge[v1_, v2_] :> Sequence[{v1, t[v1, v2]}, {v2, a[v2, v1]}], 
      {First, Head@#[[2]] &}] },
   Flatten[Replace[gb, p : {{_, (_a | _t)} ..} :> 
    Equal[(Head[p[[1, 2]]] /. {a -> α, t -> τ})[p[[1, 1]]], 
      Total[p[[All, 2]]]], ∞], 1]]&;  
vInfoStockCapF = Module[{g = subGraphF[##]},  
   Mean[#[[All, 1]]] <= Mean[#[[All, 2]]] & /@ 
     GatherBy[PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] <= 
        PropertyValue[{g, #[[2]]}, VertexCapacity] & /@ 
          EdgeList@subGraphF[##], Last]] &;
allConstraintsF = Flatten[Through[{feasibleF, vInfoStockCapF, attentionAllocationF, 
   flowBalanceF}@##]] &; 
objective = t[5, 3] a[3, 5] x[5];
modelF = {{objective, And @@ allConstraintsF[##]},  decisionVarsF[##]} &;
instanceF[params_] := modelF[##] /. Flatten[Thread[#[[1]] -> #[[2]]] & /@ 
  Thread[Array[#, 5] & /@ {x, τ, α} -> params]] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
modelF[wG1, 5, 2]
```

> {{a[3, 5] t[5, 3] x[5],
>     0 <= a[1, 3] <= 1 && 0 <= a[2, 1] <= 1 && 0 <= a[2, 4] <= 1 && 
>      0 <= a[3, 5] <= 1 && 0 <= a[4, 3] <= 1 && 0 <= t[1, 2] <= 1 && 
>      0 <= t[3, 1] <= 1 && 0 <= t[3, 4] <= 1 && 0 <= t[4, 2] <= 1 && 
>      0 <= t[5, 3] <= 1 &&
>   a[3, 5] t[5, 3] x[5] <= x[3] &&
>      a[4, 3] t[3, 4] x[3] <= x[4] &&
>      1/2 (a[2, 1] t[1, 2] x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODFXu.png) + a[2, 4] t[4, 2] x[4]) <= x[2] &&
>      a[1, 3] t[3, 1] x[3] <= x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODFXu.png) &&
>   τ[5] ==  t[5, 3] &&
>   α[3] == a[3, 5] &&
>   τ[3] == t[3, 1] + t[3, 4] &&
>   α[4] == a[4, 3] &&
>   τ[4] == t[4, 2] && α[2] == a[2, 1] + a[2, 4] &&
>   α[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODFXu.png) == a[1, 3] &&
>   τ[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODFXu.png) == t[1, 2] &&
>     a[1, 3] t[3, 1] x[3] + a[4, 3] t[3, 4] x[3] == 
>       a[3, 5] t[5, 3] x[5] &&
>      a[2, 4] t[4, 2] x[4] == a[4, 3] t[3, 4] x[3] &&
>      0 == a[2, 1] t[1, 2] x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODFXu.png) + a[2, 4] t[4, 2] x[4]},
>   {a[1, 3], a[2, 1], a[2, 4], a[3, 5], a[4, 3], t[1, 2], t[3, 1], t[3, 4], 
>     t[4, 2], t[5, 3]}}

```
parameters = {xx, tt, aa} = {{1, 3, 3, 15, 3}, {.7, 0, .8, .3, .8}, {.9, .7, .6, .7, 0}};

instanceF[parameters][wG1, 5, 2]
```

> {{3 a[3, 5] t[5, 3],
>     0 <= a[1, 3] <= 1 && 0 <= a[2, 1] <= 1 && 0 <= a[2, 4] <= 1 && 
>      0 <= a[3, 5] <= 1 && 0 <= a[4, 3] <= 1 && 0 <= t[1, 2] <= 1 && 
>      0 <= t[3, 1] <= 1 && 0 <= t[3, 4] <= 1 && 0 <= t[4, 2] <= 1 && 
>      0 <= t[5, 3] <= 1 &&
>   3 a[3, 5] t[5, 3] <= 3 &&
>      3 a[4, 3] t[3, 4] <= 15 &&
>      1/2 (a[2, 1] t[1, 2] + 15 a[2, 4] t[4, 2]) <= 3 &&
>      3 a[1, 3] t[3, 1] <= 1 &&
>   0.8 == t[5, 3] &&
>    0.6 == a[3, 5] &&
>      0.8 == t[3, 1] + t[3, 4] &&
>    0.7 == a[4, 3] &&
>   0.3 == t[4, 2] &&
>      0.7 == a[2, 1] + a[2, 4] &&
>    0.9 == a[1, 3] &&
>    0.7 == t[1, 2] &&
>      3 a[1, 3] t[3, 1] + 3 a[4, 3] t[3, 4] == 3 a[3, 5] t[5, 3] &&
>      15 a[2, 4] t[4, 2] == 3 a[4, 3] t[3, 4] &&
>      0 == a[2, 1] t[1, 2] + 15 a[2, 4] t[4, 2]},
>   {a[1, 3], a[2, 1], 
>     a[2, 4], a[3, 5], a[4, 3], t[1, 2], t[3, 1], t[3, 4], t[4, 2], 
>     t[5, 3]}}

```
NMaximize @@  instanceF[parameters][wG1,5,2]
```

> NMaximize::nosat: Obtained solution does not satisfy the following constraints within Tolerance -> 0.001: {3 a[4,3] t[3,4]-15 a[2,4] t[4,2]==0,-a[2,1] t[1,2]-15 a[2,4] t[4,2]==0,3 a[1,3] t[3,1]+3 a[4,3] t[3,4]-3 a[3,5] t[5,3]==0}.
>
> {1.44, {a[1, 3] -> 0.9, a[2, 1] -> 0.636639, a[2, 4] -> 0.0633612, 
>     a[3, 5] -> 0.6, a[4, 3] -> 0.7, t[1, 2] -> 0.7, t[3, 1] -> 0.37037, 
>     t[3, 4] -> 0.42963, t[4, 2] -> 0.3, t[5, 3] -> 0.8}}

**Note:** if we replace `Equal` with `GreaterEqual` in definition of `attentionAllocationF` above then we get a solution without infeasibility warning:

```
solution  = NMaximize @@  instanceF[parameters][wG1,5,2]
```

> {1., {a[1, 3] -> 0.580483, a[2, 1] -> 2.82245*10^-12, 
>     a[2, 4] -> 0.0553563, a[3, 5] -> 0.598288, 
>     a[4, 3] -> 1.01812*10^-12, t[1, 2] -> 0.117302, t[3, 1] -> 0.574234,
>      t[3, 4] -> 0.224126, t[4, 2] -> 5.48145*10^-13, 
>     t[5, 3] -> 0.557145}}

At this solution none of the attention allocation constraints is binding:

```
attentionAllocationF[wG1, 5, 2] /. GreaterEqual -> Equal /. 
  Flatten[Thread[#[[1]] -> #[[2]]] & /@ 
   Thread[Array[#, 5] & /@ {x, τ, α} -> parameters]]  /. solution[[2]]
```

> {False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False}

Another example with vertex 1 as the sink:

```
NMaximize @@ instanceF[parameters][wG1, 5, 1]
```

> {1.44, {a[1, 2] -> 0.54086, a[1, 3] -> 0.0226264, a[2, 4] -> 0.474469,
>        a[3, 5] -> 0.6, a[4, 3] -> 0.645526, t[2, 1] -> 0., 
>       t[3, 1] -> 0.00494044, t[3, 4] -> 0.743407, t[4, 2] -> 0.202284, 
>       t[5, 3] -> 0.8}}

Comment: used `τ[i]` for `t[i]` and `α[i]` for `a[i]` to avoid using the same symbols for parameters and decision variables.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, I am glad a few hours fun produced something useful for someone:) If you want to cite in your paper any part of this post you can use the link. Curios about the context in which you use this; if you provide a link to your paper I would like read it. Best.

Comment: Thank you @Tugrul.

Comment: Your very welcome. Thank you.

Comment: I studied your `code`, and it seems we need to revise it only slightly: (1) I edited the question and indicated the 5 constraints to be revised/added as `NEW`, which are the only pieces that need to be included in the code. (2) Given a sub-graph, the objective function can also be automated as `sum of all the edge weights of the paths originating from the source node (s) times x[s]`. (3) `bc4` ensures that total inflow to the target node (t) `=` total outflow from the source (s). (4) The vertex constraints `(fc4,  fc5, fc6)`all together ensure the closure of the sub-graph concerned.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, I will update the post with necessary modifications.

Comment: Thanks very much indeed.

Answer (score 3):

My answer below is only for purposes of completeness. @kglr's contribution produced this `code`, and I made few slight adjustments to @kglr's `code` to reflect a fully consistent max-flow problem.

```
(****************************************************)
(*  [1] Symbolic formulation of the Max-Flow model  *)
(****************************************************)
ClearAll[edgeW, subGraphF, objectiveF, flowBalanceF1, flowBalanceF2, 
  vInfoStockCapF, attentionAllocationF, feasibleF, allConstraintsF, 
  decisionVarsF, modelF, instanceF];

(* Identify all the pathways from a source to a sink in a digraph *)
edgeW = Module[{g = #, 
     e = DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ 
       FindPath[##, \[Infinity], All]}, 
    Transpose[{e, PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ # & /@ e}]] &;

(* The Max-Flow Model: all the functions below have 3 inputs: \
(digraph, source, sink)   *)
(* all paths from a source vertex to a sink vertex: a subgraph *)
subGraphF = Module[
    {el = edgeW[##][[All, 1]]},
    Graph[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@el], 
     VertexCapacity -> {v_ :> PropertyValue[{#, v}, VertexCapacity]}, 
     EdgeWeight -> {e_ :> PropertyValue[{#, e}, EdgeWeight]}]] &;

(* objective function as the sum of the edge weights of those paths \
originating from the sink vertex *)
objectiveF = 
  Module[{eList, source, sink, g = subGraphF[##], s = #2, t = #3},
    eList = DeleteDuplicates[EdgeList@g]; 
    source = Cases[eList, DirectedEdge[s, _]]; 
    sink = Cases[eList, DirectedEdge[_, t]]; 
    Simplify@Total[PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ source]] &;

(* flow balancing conditions in "subGraphF" *)
flowBalanceF1 = Module[
    {g = subGraphF[##]}, 
    DeleteCases[
     Equal @@ (Total[
            PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ 
             Cases[EdgeList[g], #]] & /@ {DirectedEdge[#, _], 
           Reverse[DirectedEdge[#, _]]}) & /@ 
      Rest[VertexList@g], (_ == 0) | (0 == _)]] &;

flowBalanceF2 = 
  Module[{eList, source, sink, g = subGraphF[##], s = #2, t = #3},
    eList = DeleteDuplicates[EdgeList@g]; 
    source = Cases[eList, DirectedEdge[s, _]]; 
    sink = Cases[eList, DirectedEdge[_, t]]; 
    Equal @@ {Simplify@
       Total[PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ source], 
      Simplify@Total[PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ sink]}] &;

(* vertex capacity constraints: ..\[LessEqual]\[Nu][i] for all i *)
vInfoStockCapF = Module[
    {g = subGraphF[##]},
    Total[#[[All, 1]]] <= Mean[#[[All, 2]]] & /@ 
     GatherBy[
      PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] <= 
         PropertyValue[{g, #[[2]]}, VertexCapacity] & /@ 
       EdgeList@subGraphF[##], Last]] &;

(* attention allocation constraints: ..\[LessEqual]\[Tau][i] and \
..\[LessEqual]\[Alpha][i] for all i *)
attentionAllocationF = 
  Module[{gb = 
      GatherBy[
       EdgeList[subGraphF[##]] /. 
        DirectedEdge[v1_, v2_] :> 
         Sequence[{v1, t[v1, v2]}, {v2, a[v2, v1]}], {First, 
        Head@#[[2]] &}]}, 
    Flatten[Replace[gb, 
      p : {{_, (_a | _t)} ..} :> 
       GreaterEqual[(Head[p[[1, 2]]] /. {a -> \[Alpha], t -> \[Tau]})[
         p[[1, 1]]], Total[p[[All, 2]]]], \[Infinity]], 1]] &;
(* attention feasibility conditions for all the decision variables in \
"subGraphF" *)
feasibleF = Thread[0 <= decisionVarsF[##]] &;

(* all the constraints gathered *)
allConstraintsF = 
  Flatten[Through[{feasibleF, vInfoStockCapF, attentionAllocationF, 
       flowBalanceF1, flowBalanceF2}@##]] &;

(* decision variables in "subGraphF" *)
decisionVarsF = 
  Union@Flatten[
     EdgeList[subGraphF[##]] /. 
      DirectedEdge[v1_, v2_] :> {t[v1, v2], a[v2, v1]}] &;

(* full model for a specific "subGraphF" *)
modelF = {{objectiveF[##], And @@ allConstraintsF[##]}, 
   decisionVarsF[##]} &;  (* model formulation *)

(* model solution for specific parameter values "parameters" *)
instanceF[params_] := 
 modelF[##] /. 
   Flatten[Thread[#[[1]] -> #[[2]]] & /@ 
     Thread[Array[#, n] & /@ {\[Nu], \[Tau], \[Alpha]} -> params]] &;
```